# Date Filter Webpart

Tags: web-part

After setting up a date filter web part, my list doesn't show all items. It just shows items whose date are equal to the date of my date filter web part.

Are there any ways to set the date in date filter web part blank and my list shows all of the items at the beginning?

Comment: Check the link https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/sharepoint-list-filtering-by-date-range.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since the date filter is set to a specific date it will filter the items based on that parameter. In order to change this, the default date needs to be changed.

Go to 'Edit Page'

Select the 'Date Filter' web part and select the 'Edit Web part' option

Expand the 'Filter' option tab and set the Default Value to None.

Click 'OK' and load the page again.

This should have the date filter to be blank in the beginning and it will display all of the items in the list.